# Can you call a REST service from Eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse, rest

Can we call a rest service from Eclipse?

We can call REST service from workbench to test whether its working fine or not. If you want to see the logs, we wont be able to see the whole log in developer console as there is a limit for log size, but in Eclipse we can see the whole log.

That is why I want to know, if there is a way to call REST service from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we do not have sophisticate plugin in eclipse that will let you play with REST api.

There is plugin for SOAP api only (SOAP UI).

There is one workaround that you can use.

Write code in anonymous block of clips and check the log there.

e.g.

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setEndpoint('https://external.service.com');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody('');
    req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
```